# Symfony 3 - Refactor controller action

Tags: php, symfony, refactoring, action

I’m working on a Symfony 3 project wher I discovered a very long controller action (like 1k lines and lany different treatments inside) that I want to refactor by cutting it into several other functions.

My controller has already a lot of actions and functions, and I don’t know if it’s a good idea to multiply the functions inside.

What is the cleanest way to refactor this kind of function ? Should I make a service only for this action ?

Comment: I'd either group logic by topic or functionality and - yes - create a service for that. Controller, overall should be kept to a mininum. Code in services can be reused whereas code in controllers cannot. But regarding symfony 3 you would be recommended to create a bundle for this, right? As far as i know. (Never used symfony 3).
Needles to point out its unmaintained and should not be used in any productive environment.

Comment: As @Jonathan says, try to identify repeated code, abstract it to a Service if it will be consumed in others Controllers or in private funcion.

Comment: Thank’s for your answers, I’ll go with services and repositories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Jonathan says, try to identify repeated code, abstract it to a Service if it will be consumed in others Controllers/Services.

In symfony 3, you have available [repositories](https://symfony.com/doc/3.0/doctrine/repository.html), you could try to identify repeated querys on the controller and move it to the repository of the entity.

Also, if you are app is creating forms in the controller, you could move it to Form clases to reduce code in your controller. [Creating form clases](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes)

I hope that helps you to reduce code in your controllerss